# Ping server every second to see uptime

Tags: linux, shell, unix, cron, ping

I am writing a quick and dirty script to detect server downtime. I have one server and two remote clients that ping the server every second to see if it is up.

How would I set a task to run every second on the client machine, if the most you can run `cron` is one time per minute? What would be the best way to accopmlish the above?

In addition, the client machine may restart, and the program will need to keep running (similar to cron here).

Comment: ping does by default ping in 1 second intervals ... what are you trying to do above of that?

Comment: Well, I need to update the database after each second, so it's basically a one-second function that I want to put in a non-ending loop...Ping is only part of the function.

Comment: What happens if the server restarts? How would the program continue?

Comment: I suggest that this is only the start of a whole host of monitoring that you will want to do.  I suggest looking at a package like Nagios rather than creating your own. http://www.nagios.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while true; do ping -c 1 server | do stuff w/ output;sleep 1;done
```

To qualify for the "edit (may reboot)" just create an init-script that
starts the loop again.

Answer (score 2):

I know you asked about ping.  There are other things to consider as well.

A more reasonable way to get "uptime"  is to use the something that queries a database like wtpmx, utmp, or other files meant for this.  The ping protocol, ICMP can be and will be ignored by a busy system.  A missed return does not always mean the system is down.  Or the system is not working.
There can be a lot of reasons.

One way to consider getting uptime on a modern UNIX box:

```
ssh remoteserver 'uptime'
```

Also consider "why" you are pinging.

Ping is useful to check if a system is alive and responds to ping packets,, but may not tell you if a system is actually functioning.  This is probably what you want to know for sure. For example, a database server or mailserver may have some hung processes.  So it responds to ping but does very little of what it is intended to do.  You may want to construct a more useful command than just ping.  We log into a 24x7 prod database on a server once per minute and have it run a sql script that echoes something harmless like 'OKAY'.  e.g.,

```
select 'OKAY' from dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a cronjob to achieve this with the help of the following script.

`1 * * * * /bin/ping -c2 www.google.com | while read pong; do echo "$(date): $pong"; done >> ~/pings/google.com.log`

It pings google.com every 1 min & logs the output with current date & time to the file path.

Comment: Very nice. One could use 1.1.1.1 (CloudFlare) to not rely on Google.